# Sending central config to microservices in .net core

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, microservices

I am researching how to have a **centralized data store** for a multi-tenant application. This is a microservice application.

For example, each tenant will have different values for some keys. Some tenants will have their own unique keys, but let's assume they are all the same for now.

I have one microservice responsible for **CRUD** of the tenant configuration.

I need that configuration to be **pushed** to all of the other microservices so that each **sub-service** can have its own **copy** of the **configuration** and there is no reliance on the configuration service being up.

To me, this should be infrastructure instead of custom C# code but I am new to the microservices scene so wondering if there is a known approach.

I considered using **MassTransit/messages** but then wouldn't every microservice need a duplicated **POCO/Contract** class? Also if there is a new key required, all microservices would need to be updated and deployed, which breaks the purpose of microservices.

In short, how can I have a config micro service sync tenant-specific data to multiple other microservices?

Comment: Why not use a common database as a backplane for the services, e.g. Cosmos DB?

Comment: Use services like [Azure AppConfiguration](https://azure.microsoft.com/de-de/services/app-configuration/) or [launchdarkly](https://launchdarkly.com/) if your services are able to access the internet. Both provide a very well documented integration in net (core)